# Adding shortcut for recording entire screen from screenshots app

Tags: screen-capture, screen-recording

Is there some way to add or create the shortcut to record the screen instantly?
The current way to do it is `Cmd+Shift+5` > `Click record entire screen` > `Click anywhere to start`.
The expected way would be to do the above three with a single shortcut, maybe `Cmd+Shift+6`.

Comment: Are you after a snapshot? I use cmnd+shift+3 for the entire screen and cmnd+shift+4 for a selected section.

Comment: There's no way to do it from the regular control panel - 'stills' are key-commandable, but the only option for the new cmd/shift/5 is to that 'front page'. Maybe some 3rd party app could do it, but idk of one.